# Display value of javascript variable in webpage table

Tags: javascript, html, xslt

I have a Javascript variable `Pass`  which holds value that I got from my XSLT. I want to display  the value of  `Pass` in my html webpage  inside a table. The variable `Pass` definitely holds a value. I am able to get in in a alert box using the alert() function, But, i am not able to get this value to my webpage.

I have so far tried these two but they dont seem to work.

```
    <td> Pass</td>
    <td> document.write(Pass) </td>
```

Here is the section of code, where I need help:

```
<table>      
     <script type="text/javascript">     
         var Total='<xsl:value-of select="@total" />'
         var Failure='<xsl:value-of select="@errors" />'

         var Pass= Total - Failure

         <tr> 
             <td>Pass </td>
             <td> *Value of the variable 'Pass' goes here* </td>
         </tr>   
    </script>
</table>
```

Comment: you can't have html directly in javascript. it has to be a string. might i suggest a template engine? also you can't just subtract strings like that.

Comment: Yes. Please let me know if it is simple..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using XSLT anyway, just use XSLT to output the value instead of JavaScript:

```
<table>
    <tr> 
        <td>Pass </td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="@total - @errors"/></td>
    </tr>
<table>
```

Comment: Thanks!. The most simpe solution worked brilliantly and save several lines of code and inclusion of javascript.

Answer (score 1):

```
<table>
         <tr> 
             <td>Pass </td>
             <td> *Value of the variable '<span id="PassId">Pass</span>' goes here* </td>
         </tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">   
    var Total='<xsl:value-of select="@total" />'
    var Failure='<xsl:value-of select="@errors" />'

    var Pass= Total - Failure;
    document.getElementById('PassId').innerHTML = Pass;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign the element you want the value to appear in an id.

Eg `<td id="myexample"><\td>`

You can now easily access that element from JavaScript.

```
var myexample = document.getElementById("myexample");
myexample.innerHTML = "your value here";
```

Comment: This should address the question asked but as pointed out by Daniel, there are other problems with your code

Answer (score 0):

As long as you can get your XSLT to render the value correctly for vars Total and Failure. The following can work:

```
<html><body>
<table>      
    <tr> 
        <td>Pass </td>
            <td> *Value of the variable <span id="passval"></span> goes here* </td>
        </tr>   
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">     
    var Total='<xsl:value-of select="@total" />'
    var Failure='<xsl:value-of select="@errors" />'

    var Pass= Total-Failure;
    var passvalholder = document.getElementById("passval");
    passvalholder.innerHTML=Pass;
</script>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Thanks! This solution worked, but I'm going with the Thomas' solution. I have avoided javascript by going with the XSLT addition & subtraction